# How do I restore Windows 7 from my external HDD with Linux Mint 18.1?

Tags: windows-7, linux-mint, windows-7-backup

I bought a laptop with Windows 7 and backed it up onto my portable hard drive. I then wiped it from my laptops hard drive when installing Linux Mint. I have already backed up Mint. I would like to restore my windows 7 onto my laptop as some applications for my studies cannot be used on Mint, e.g. Construct 2.

Comment: How did you backup windows 7?

Answer (score 1):

The answer depends on how you backed up your Windows 7.

### Windows 7 Backup

I see that you have put a Windows 7 Backup tag, so I assume you did that Windows 7 Backup.

If so, insert a Windows 7 installation disc or installation USB flash drive into your laptop and boot from it.

[image: The first screen of Windows Setup]

Once you are inside Windows Setup, click "Repair your computer". From there, you can run Windows Backup and restore your computer from your backup.

[image: System Recovery Options]

### Third party backup utilities

If you used third party backup utilities, you must consult their developers for a rescue disk. For example, Acronis True Image allows your to make a rescue disk with which you can boot your computer and run a copy of Acronis True Image which helps you restore your computer. I am aware that backup solutions from Paragon, SuperEasy and AOMEI also have such rescue disks.

[image: Acronis Rescue Media]

### If you backed up your computer using simple file copy...

... You are screwed. Sorry.

Consult your laptop manufacturer's website for receiving a recovery media.